# Multiple objects together JAVA Sockets

Tags: java, sockets, http

I was experimenting with HTTP GET requests via JAVA sockets ( I know there are better libraries but isn't experiencing is the best way to learning) "Issuing multiple GET requests together" is the part I'm stuck with. I can write two lines (one for each) but how would I know if they were actually sent together (most probably they won't be as I've a multithreaded program)?

Comment: For analyzing what's going on the line, some tool like wireshark is always very valuable. What do you exactly mean by "sent **together**"?

Comment: If two GET requests are "sent together", it means that the second GET along with the first GET without waiting for the 200 OK (or whatever) of the first one.